# Sub Resource Integrity value for //maps.google.com/maps/api/js

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cdn, subresource-integrity

Where do i find the sub resource integrity value for the script //maps.google.com/maps/api/js?

For example:

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js" integrity="sha256-????" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to generate integrity Hash code,  you can use this website :

https://www.srihash.org/

you paste your URL and then generate the hash online.  However,  I don't think it's possible to do it with google Maps API.  I get the following message :

> Error: this resource is not eligible for integrity checks. See http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Same problem. Does anyone know if google is likely to enable CORS?

Answer (score 32):

You don't find the SRI digest for that script, and even if you did it wouldn't help you.

**You don't:**

SRI hashes are for content that doesn't change. Google changes the code that underlies their API all the time. You don't get to pick which version of the API to use; they choose for you, which is why there's no version number in that script path.

Using SRI for the Google Maps API script doesn't actually provide any additional security because that script's whole job is to download the newest version of a set of other scripts that actually provide the API functionality.

You can't use SRI to validate those other scripts, so you're already obligated to trust Google's security or forgo using their Maps API.

**Even if you did, it wouldn't be helpful:**

For scripts that don't download other JS files, try scrolling a bit lower down on the srihash.org site.

It says you can generate the SRI digest yourself using the Linux shell command `openssl dgst -sha384 -binary FILENAME.js | openssl base64 -A`

However that still won't help you with sites like this that don't serve the content with CORS headers because the browser requires CORS in order to do the SRI validation. Without the proper CORS headers, the browser won't even try to compare the script to the SRI digest.

There's an explanation of the thought processes behind the decision to require CORS here: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec/issues/338#issuecomment-99766294

The upshot is that since SRI hashes are for all types of resources (not just JS and CSS files that have a legacy exception to the whole CORS thing) it could be used to get around same-origin policy enough to sniff otherwise inaccessible content.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for the Google Maps API.

As you can read here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries this javascript library is updated once in a while. Also if you use a fixed version number as parameter in the url this get updated.