# Jekyll compilation: Process completed with exit code 1 on Github

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, mathjax

I am using [cayman theme for github](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman) for writing scientific articles which i can host  on Github pages. I am using mathjax to render equations.

I have pasted the following lines inside the `cayman/_includes/head-custom.html` file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>
```

Mathjax renders the math equations correctly (local and remote), but it produces an error on Github (image attached). I can not make anything out of this error, I am a little concerned that it may create bigger issue later on.

Any guesses why this error and how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your [`html-proofer`](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer) test script implementation is set to check for [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)/[`SRI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) on external js resources and thus is throwing a validation error because it's expecting a couple of additional attributes on all `<script>` tags (that aren't there currently on the tags in question), `crossorigin="anonymous"` and `integrity="...insert-sha256-value-here..."`

My understanding is that SRI needs to be supported by the developer and therefore the `integrity` value should be coming from them.

If [`MathJax`](https://www.mathjax.org/) hasn't provided an `integrity` value along with their CDN script code then I think you may need to disable checking for `CORS`/`SRI` to eliminate the error.

Do you have access to the script that contains the command that runs `html-proofer`, and if so, can you see if it's checking for SRI? Might look something like this:

```sh
htmlproofer --check-sri ...
```

According to the [`html-proofer` docs](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer#configuration), `--check-sri` defaults to `false`, so if this option is being set and you can disable it, I'd give that a try.

Comment: FYI according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374880/sub-resource-integrity-value-for-maps-google-com-maps-api-js) there is a way you can generate your own `integrity` value but it sounds brittle. And there may be an issue if your script src path includes a specific version number.

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1366), adding SRI support to MathJax is an open feature request.