# google reCaptcha integrity-check and CORS

Tags: cors, recaptcha, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

I've successfully integrated google reCaptcha into my website.

> `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>`

It works OK. Now I', trying to make it more sucure.
Adding Content-Security-Policy to .htaccess also worked well.

> `Header always set Content-Security-Policy ... Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.google.com/" Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET"`

Still works OK, but the problems begin when trying to add script integrity check:

> `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" integrity="sha512-s0NDd+2SST8+KCauhNc/r3PNSANq9TalIblRZkc+7ZqpHmo0bA+r/GJXTEygfi7Y+LgzuoHO7+1SQNuw8EbevA==" crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>`

At this point browser refuses to work and throws bunch of errors at me:

> `Access to script at 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' from origin 'https://mysite.lt' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. index.php:16          GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js net::ERR_FAILED 200`

As you can see, Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set, but error persists.
Tried lots of workarounds, like removing `crossorigin = "anonymous"`, or making it camelCase - crossOrigin, changing hashing to SHA256 or SHA384 but nothing works.

I believe, this particular situation should be quite common - lots of sites use reCaptcha...
How to deal with situation like this? Should I just quit checking .js integrity?

Comment: Subresource Integrity requires the resource in question (`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`) to be configured for CORS, and that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Well, so how do people pass the OWASP test? "Sub Resource Integrity Attribute Missing" is flagged as medium risk level. And Captcha is mandatory for this site...

Comment: Not sure if it's a solvable problem if Google doesn't configure CORS on that resource. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374880/sub-resource-integrity-value-for-maps-google-com-maps-api-js. See also https://groups.google.com/g/recaptcha/c/BFY3TZ-2g3w